# Zend framework application to apache2 webserver

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, ubuntu

This is probably a noob question but i'm really new to this thing (zend application & apache2 servers)
previous developers have given me the source code for the project they did and he said that it was created with Zend framework. I've managed to run it on my computer (Windows 7) under XAMPP server. If I go to http://****(mylocalcomputer)/ it will work. But once I copy all (3 folders) of them on the Ubuntu web server we have, it's not working. I've tried pointing the directory (configuring /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default000) to the public folder like the ones I did on XAMPP httpd.conf, but it's still not working...
After trying it in chrome, I go to inspect element, and going thru console, it's telling me all the files mentioned with 404 not found errors. But when I browse with winscp to the directories, I can find those files. Help please... thanks in advance...

Comment: Two thoughts:  1. Did you restart apache after modifying the sites-enabled/default000 file? 2. When something works on Windows and fails on Linux, it's often an issue of case-sensitivity in the filesystem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply David! Yeah, I did restart the apache service. I'm really new to this thing, but I managed to make it work :)

Comment: Just keep at it. It's a lot to get your head around, but slowly, eventually, it really does all come into focus. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED this problem...I just have to carefully configure all the Aliases and Directory Root properly. THANKS to this website, I was able to check all the possible causes and errors of that default000 file!